# PHP string without quotes

Tags: php, upgrade, php-7, php-5.3, php-8

I'm upgrading an exsiting application from php 5.3 to php 7.
I found this code in the application `$this->upload_err = ERR_CORRUPTION;`
I didn't found any const whith the name `ERR_CORRUPTION`

can we use string without quotes in PHP 5 ?

Comment: You can check [string syntax in official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax).

Comment: There were indeed unquoted strings in older versions of PHP (treated as constants), deprecated in version 7.2 : https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration72.deprecated.php

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no...

Somewhere during the development of PHP 3.0 (in 1998), a feature was added to allow unquoted strings; but before 3.0 came out, a different feature was added with the same syntax: constants.

Although the unquoted strings were never in a released version of PHP, they were retained as a fallback: PHP would first check if there was a constant with that name, and if not, treat it as a string. Whenever it fell back, it would issue an E_NOTICE, but a lot of people ignored these.

In PHP 7.2, the severity was raised to an E_WARNING, and the feature was [officially deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration72.deprecated.php). In PHP 8.0, [it was raised to an Error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php).

So, this code was never technically *correct*, and the capital letters suggest that a constant definition was *intended*; but in PHP versions below 8.0, it will *run* even if the constant is undefined, acting as though you had run `define('ERR_CORRUPTION', 'ERR_CORRUPTION');`